# Выражение || всегда равно ненулевой константе

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Не могу понять предупреждение. 
Предупреждение C6236 (<выражение> || <ненулевая константа>) всегда равно ненулевой константе.
Что в этом коде не так написано? Сущетсвует другое или специально для строк?

```
bool fun()
{
    char str5 = 'б';
    if (str5 == 'а' || 'б' )
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что `(str5 == 'а') || 'б'` Всегда `true`. Может `str5 == 'а' || str5 == 'б'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше выражение дословно читается как:

```
if ( (str5 == 'a') || true ) { ... } /* ВСЕГДА true */
```

Быть может вы хотели написать:

```
if ( (str5 == 'a') || (str5 == 'b') ) { ... }
```

?